# How to find white space between Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML that looks something like this

```
<element>Example xml</element>    <element>Example XML</element>
```

I need the number of white spaces between the two element nodes. Is this possible in XSLT?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the first `element` element is the current context node, then the XPath

```
following-sibling::text()[1]
```

would give you the text node between the two elements, so

```
string-length(following-sibling::text()[1])
```

would give you its length.  This assumes that you *don't* have an `<xsl:strip-space>` instruction in your stylesheet - if you have one of those then the processor would strip out the whitespace-only text node at parse time, and your stylesheet would see the two `element` elements as being adjacent with no text node between them.

Comment: IF I had to have strip space for other elements and it is instantiated at the highest level of the code is there any way to override it for one matching method?

Comment: @HansHansen You can countermand `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` with an `<xsl:preserve-space elements="parent-of-element"/>` (with the appropriate name for the element that is the immediate parent of your `element` elements).